# Ubuntu login loop in terminal too

Tags: login

I really need help right now I restarted my laptop which runs Ubuntu and now I can't log in I tried to use ctrl+alt+f3 but when I log in in the terminal same thing happens, it loops again, what can I do?

Comment: Can you give me a screenshot?

Comment: I can't, I don't have points to put photo.

Comment: I only see this:

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS ASUS-RAZVAN tty3 and then down: ASUS-RAZVAN login:

Comment: I think because I was trying to add to Path variable some file and when I was still loged in I opened the terminal and I got some error that someting was missing I tried to fix it deleting what I added in .bash_profile and I restarted my computer, and now I  can't log in and also when I try to log in with ctrl+alt+f3 I enter my name and password I see a greeting message and then it asks me again for my name and password.

Comment: To reinstall my OS I need to have a USB with Ubuntu on it, or is there a way to reinstall it without it?